# PostMessage from serviceWorker after push event

Tags: javascript, postmessage, service-worker

I need to send message from serviceWorker to page after push-event.
I can't specify the port property (like https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/demos/postMessage/) because I did not send this message

This code does not work (maybe I'm doing something wrong)

```
self.registration.active.postMessage('fsdfasf');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the [specs](https://slightlyoff.github.io/ServiceWorker/spec/service_worker/#client) what it seems to be the right implementation is picking a `Client` from the Service Worker and then using the `postMessage` method, eg:

```
onmessage = function(event){
  clients.matchAll().then(function(clients){
    clients[0].postMesssage('yourmessage');
  });
}
```

Comment: And to listen for this message on the controlled page, you should use something like `navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('ServiceWorkerMessageEvent', function(e) {...});` This changed starting in Chrome 45; see https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5163630974730240

Comment: @JeffPosnick actually this works: `navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', e => console.log(e));`